# Create variable tag from XML tag value

Tags: xml, xslt

Is it possible to change given XML structure

```
<Cars>
    <Car>Honda</Car>
    <Car>Ferrari</Car>
</Cars>
```

with XLST to

```
<Cars>
    <Honda></Honda>
    <Ferrari></Ferrari>
</Cars>
```

I know XSLT a little, but I'm not sure how to create variable tags.

Thanks everybody.
I appreciate all three answers and have up voted them.

Comment: you'll need a template which at least matches the root element (when answering before I assumed this was a small example as part of a larger XSLT). I've updated my answer to include `<xsl:template match="/">`.

Comment: thanks for quick answer, I'm only starting to learn XLST, if it weren't for that, I would have accepted your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
      xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates />
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Cars">
        <Cars>
            <xsl:for-each select="Car">
                <xsl:element name="{.}"/>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </Cars>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 3):

You're looking for `xsl:element`, with a name computed at run-time using curly braces like so:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each select="Cars/Car">
        <xsl:element name="{.}"/>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use [<xsl:element>](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#section-Creating-Elements-with-xsl%3aelement) to create elements by a given name. E.g. in your case it will be something like:

```
<xsl:template match="Car">
    <xsl:element name="{text()}"></xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

UPD:
This is a fragment. Usually it is a good approach for such transformations which intended just to modify a few nodes in the tree. You define the copy-template:

```
<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

which just copies the whole xml tree as is and then add some customised templates for particular elements, attributes, etc, e.g. as for the "Car" above.